# How to write xUnit Test for a method which calls another method in its body?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

This is the class contains **EnqueueJobAsync** method which I want to write test for it :

```
public class ConsumerBaseForTesting
{
    protected IJobStore JobStore { get; private set; }

    public ConsumerBaseForTesting(IJobStore jobStore)
    {
        JobStore = jobStore;
    }

    public async Task<IJob> EnqueueJobAsync(IJob job)
        => await JobStore.CreateAsync(job);
}
```

This is my test which **Fails** and its **actual** return is always **NULL** !

```
public class ConsumerBaseTest
{


    private readonly Mock<IJobStore> _moqIJobStore;
    private readonly ConsumerBaseForTesting _consumerBase;

    public ConsumerBaseTest()
    {
        _moqIJobStore = new Mock<IJobStore>();
        _consumerBase = new ConsumerBaseForTesting(_moqIJobStore.Object);
    }


    [Theory]
    [ClassData(typeof(JobClassForTesting))]
    public async Task EnqueueJobAsyncTest(IJob job)
    {
        var jobResult = await _consumerBase.EnqueueJobAsync(job);

        Assert.Equal(job, jobResult);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I think your mock isn't setup to return anything from the function so it returns null. Check the docs on how to customize its behavior: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#methods

Comment: When I write the first code like this :

public async Task<IJob> EnqueueJobAsync(IJob job)
        => await job;

it returns job as what I expect.

but it returns Null when it goes to CreatAsync Method in another Class.

Comment: Can you add the code which has setup for method call and return value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mock needs to be setup to do two things in order to replicate the expected behavior.

It needs to return the passed job in a completed task.

```
//...

public ConsumerBaseTest() {
    _moqIJobStore = new Mock<IJobStore>();
    _consumerBase = new ConsumerBaseForTesting(_moqIJobStore.Object);

    //setup the mock to capture and return the job when CreateAsync(IJob job) is invoked
    _moqIJobStore
        .Setup(_ => _.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<IJob>()))
        .Returns((IJob x) => Task.FromResult(x));     }

//...
```

`.Returns((IJob x) => Task.FromResult(x))` captures the argument and returns completed `Task<IJob>`

Comment: Thanks, I got closer to my answer but, I have an error in "Returns" which Says => Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Task<IJob>' because it is not a delegate type parameter 'job' hides outer parameter with the same name

Comment: @M.imp are using another variable in the construct with the same name?

Comment: does this code test that job (my test method parameter), is as same value as _consumerBase.EnqueueJobAsync(job) return ?